# How to make a custom ++, -=, += operator in lua?

Tags: lua, operators

How do I make a custom `++`, `-=`, `+=` operator in lua? Since it lacks increment/decrementing operators.

I'm trying to and here's my code:

```lua
local opTable = {}

debug.setmetatable(0, {
    __call = function(a, op)
        return opTable[op](a)
    end
})

opTable["++", int + 1] -- The rest of the code works, this is the main line that's the problem.

local x = 2;
print(x++)
```

I also want to know how to do `+=`, and `-=,` or maybe how to do `/=` or `*=` and `%=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make custom operators in Lua. It is not possible.

Your `__call` metamethod (if it actually works) would allow you to call `x("++")` (i.e. it allows you to call a number), not `x++`, and it would return x+1 without modifying x.

`opTable["++", int + 1]` makes no sense as a Lua statement. You probably wanted something like this:

```
opTable["++"] = function(int)
    return int + 1
end
```

but it still won't do what you want. The syntax will still be `x("++")` and it will return x+1 and it won't modify x.

Comment: Oh thanks, but thats sad that lua can't support using custom operators directly